# FindMinimum giving error FindMinimum::infeas:

Tags: mathematical-optimization, warning-messages

I'm trying to find the minimum y-coordinate of a point which lies on a side of an equilateral triangle. `FindMinimum` doesn't work when I change the position of the point on the side of the triangle.

Here is the code which gives the error:

```
FindMinimum[
  {y3,(x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2 == 20^2,
   x2^2 + y2^2 == 20^2,
   x1^2 + y1^2 == 20^2,
   (x1 - x3)^2 + (y1 - y3)^2 == 17^2,
   (x2 - x3)^2 + (y2 - y3)^2 == 3^2,
   x1 < x2,
   y1 < 0,
   y2 < 0},
  {x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, {y3, -20}}]
```

the error is:

> FindMinimum::infeas: Possible infeasibility detected. Returning the best solution found. Setting a different initial point or Method -> InteriorPoint may lead to a better solution.

The weird thing is that when I want to solve the problem which is symmetrical around the y axis, the function works and gives the correct answer.

```
FindMinimum[
  {y3, (x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2 == 20^2,
   x2^2 + y2^2 == 20^2,
   x1^2 + y1^2 == 20^2,
   (x1 - x3)^2 + (y1 - y3)^2 == 3^2,
   (x2 - x3)^2 + (y2 - y3)^2 == 17^2,
   x1 < x2,
   y1 < 0,
   y2 < 0},
  {x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, {y3, -20}}]
```

> ```
> {-18.6815, 
>    {x1 -> -2.78144, x2 -> 15.7615, x3 -> -1.3585*10^-7,
>     y1 -> -19.8056, y2 -> -12.3116, y3 -> -18.6815}}
> ```

I tried to put some other constraints to help the function to find the answer but it fails too.

[image: The Concept]

Comment: Your first code runs with absolutely no issues and in no time returns `{-18.6815, {x1 -> -15.7615, x2 -> 2.78144, x3 -> 1.41251*10^-7, 
  y1 -> -12.3116, y2 -> -19.8056, y3 -> -18.6815}}` on both `v10.4` and `v11.3`.

Comment: I'm using 11.3 student edition. could it be the issue?

Comment: No. `Quit[]` the kernel and try again; maybe you have some old definitions. I cannot help with solving a problem that I cannot reproduce.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I did what you said, but it gives the same error. Basically I simplified my question. my main problem was:

Comment: z = 7;
FindMinimum[{y5,
  x5 == 0,
  x2^2 + y2^2 == 20^2,
  x3^2 + y3^2 == 20^2,
  (x2 - x3)^2 + (y2 - y3)^2 == 20^2,
  x2 < x3,
  (x4 - x2)^2 + (y4 - y2)^2 == 20^2,
  y4 < y2 < 0,
  (x6 - x3)^2 + (y6 - y3)^2 == 20^2,
  (x4 - x6)^2 + (y4 - y6)^2 == 20^2,
  x4 < x6, (x5 - x4)^2 + (y5 - y4)^2 == z^2,
  (x5 - x6)^2 + (y5 - y6)^2 == (20 - z)^2,
  y6 < y3 < 0,
   -40 <= x2 <= 0,
   0 <= x3 <= 40,  
   -20 <= x4 <= 0,
   0 <= x6 <= 20
   },
 {x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, y2, y3, y4, {y5, -40}, y6}]

Comment: @corey979 Could you please check the code above?

Comment: Code in your last comment returns a warning and `x2->-0.001,y2->-0.001` but your code demands `x2^2+y2^2==20^2`. My code `z=7; NMinimize[{Abs[x2^2+y2^2-20^2]+ Abs[x3^2+y3^2-20^2]+ Abs[(x2-x3)^2+(y2-y3)^2-20^2]+ Abs[(x4-x2)^2+(y4-y2)^2-20^2]+ Abs[(x6-x3)^2+(y6-y3)^2-20^2]+ Abs[(x4-x6)^2+(y4-y6)^2-20^2]+ Abs[(x5-x4)^2+(y5-y4)^2-z^2]+ Abs[(x5-x6)^2+(y5-y6)^2-(20-z)^2], x5==0&&x2<x3&& y4<y2<0&&x4<x6 &&y6<y3<0&&-40<=x2<=0&&0<=x3<=40 &&-20<=x4<=0&&0<=x6<=20 &&y5<-37.5}, {x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6}, Method -> "RandomSearch"]` gives no warnings and satisfies conditions, but may not be minimum y5

Comment: @Bill Thanks for your response. As you said y5 is not minimum in the answer of your code. I know already the answer which is -37.5784. it's weird that when I change the z parameter from 7 to 13 it gives the correct answer. the problem with z=7 is the same as z=13. and this has to be true for the pair of z that their sum is 20. for instance the code works for both z=15 and z=5 and gives the same answer.